# Android :UI Thread Blocked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-intent

In my application I have created one customized dialog box ,which is showed in both webview and normal android application,and also I doing some background operation when the dialog box is showed, when ever I called the mydialog function it shows my customized dialog box and also it return some values,it is perfectly working when I use webview+javainterface but it doesn't work with ordinary applications, the flow is

first I will get my dialog, after I do some process(here the main thread will wait ,dialog need to show,) then I will return the string ,the problem is dialog doesn't show when I called this function instead of that the dialog will showed after my background process finished.

I call this my dialog box like:

```
String sample=mydialog();

public String mydialog() {

            String mystring = null;




                try {
                    myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(ShowDialog);


                    while (customizeddialog.Getvalue() == null) {

                    }

                    mystring = customizeddialog.Getvalue();
                    customizeddialog.Setvalue(null);
                } catch (Exception e) {



            return mystring;

        }

        private Runnable ShowDialog = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {


                    try {
                        customizeddialog m_dialog = new customizeddialog(myactivity.this);
                        m_dialog.setCancelable(false);
                        m_dialog.show();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }



            }
        };
```

Comment: Have you seen if the code ever exits that `while` loop?  Could you put some `Log.d("DIALOG", "code has reached point x");` statements in the code to see what's happening?  I would say using a `while` loop is not a great idea—you're better off using something like a `Handler` which you can send a message once the dialog is ready.

Comment: @AndrewWyld  ,i tried all method nothing wokrs so finallly i come to while looop but it wokrks fine  with webview, Browser.addJavascriptInterface(new myclass(this),
   "AndroidFunction");, and then i  call mydialog in javascript ,it shows my dialog and returns the value to javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter the `synchronized` block in `mydialog()` you acquire `this`'s lock. Inside this `synchronized` block, you run `ShowDialog()` on the UI thread, and try to acquire `this`'s lock again when you enter the `synchronized` block in `ShowDialog`.

Since the lock has already been acquired, it will wait until it is released in `mydialog()`, which will never happen because `ShowDialog` never executes past `synchronized(this)`. What you have is deadlock.

Comment: It could be that in your `while(customizeddialog.Get value() == null)` loop, `customizeddialog.Getvalue()` doesn't return null and the dialog wasn't shown yet.

Comment: ya agree with you but i need to value from that dialog box so that reason i put while ,but i show the dialog in uithread ,and also i put that loop in main thread,this method working fine when i call from webview

Comment: What is the type of 'customizeddialog'?

Comment: that is a separate class ,i use set and get method to get value from that class

Comment: You have `myactivity.this.runOnUiThread(ShowDialog)` immediately followed by `while (customizeddialog.Getvalue() == null)`. What if the second statement is run before `ShowDialog()` has had a chance to run? Will `customizeddialog` be null? If it is not, will `Getvalue()` return something other than null? And I'm still confused about `customizeddialog`. Is it a class or a variable? Because in `mydialog()` you call `customizeddialog.Getvalue()`. Is `Getvalue()` static? Much easier to see what's going on with clean code. Also try to post more of it so there's more of a context (no pun intended)

Comment: I've cleaned up the code, and put it here http://pastebin.com/siyqYeiP . I'm still confused about a few things. Lines 2-12, what's going on there? Lines 18 and 38 are going to cause deadlock. Lines 23 and 40, what is `Recognition`? Line 117, what is `CustomizeDialog.getstatus()`?

Comment: ya but this method is working in webview ,so what's the solution for this

Comment: If the `setfpTemplate` call in `MyThread.run()` returns right away or throws an exception the Dialog will be dismissed immediately and you'd probably never see it....can you post all of the relevant code?

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but if you want someone to debug your code, they shouldn't have to pull teeth to get the code out of you. I can't guess what it is that you're trying to do. For example, why are `getfpTemplate()` and `setfpTemplate()` static methods? What is `GeneralizationDialog`? Try re-writing your question with more information (put all relevant code there, explain what it is that you are trying to do), and try to keep it neat and formatted nicely so it is easier for others to read.